# Migration issue from GCM to FCM Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need a good solution on how can I handle/support GCM for older version builds as well as have FCM for new versions in my android app.

Problem that I am facing is, when my app is upgraded from GCM to FCM successfully, i still receive GCM message on new version builds even if i have removed all the receivers and code for it.
Now as GCM is still there running on server for older builds, I still receive GCM messages in FCM onMessageReceived().

Comment: I am not understanding your problem. Why do you want to not receive the messages in the newer version of your app ?
Btw: a simple solution could be to add a custom key-value, like: "this-message-is-for-version" = "new/old", and inside onMessageReceived() you can discard the messages you don't want.

Comment: If the problem is the topic subscriptions you should be able to unsubscribe from a topic using the FCM sdk too.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini I know that solution, thanks for that. But its just a workaround for it, not a good solution to handle it. I dont want to receive GCM messages as I trigger some functionalities in my app. Can we send data messages only to a specific version as FCM console provides. So that I dont have to code for it. It should be handled by FCM

Comment: I am sorry but currently it's not possible via the API. You can file a feature request here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini Can I unsubscribe a topic from FCM which was subscribed via GCM?? Also does FCM messages are delivered to GCM receiver if same topic is set.

Comment: yes to both the questions, underlying infrastructure is the same so GCM topics are FCM topics too - and viceversa.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoGiorgini just one more question. Is there any documentation for sending data payload message to specific version through FCm. I have searched but I dint find it mentioned anywhere

Comment: as I wrote above this is not possible via the API. only via the web console.
You can ask it as feature request here: firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Answer (score 0):

According to [fcm faq](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq)

> FCM is the new version of GCM under the Firebase brand. It inherits GCM’s core infrastructure to make sure we continue to deliver messages reliably on Android, iOS and Chrome.

So it may give you the gcm messages as well

Comment: Yes. It givess me GCM messages, But how can i handle in a good professional coding manner is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can fallow up this official Migration doc Google Cloud messaging to Firebase cloud messaging.

please see the guides for migrating in [Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).

Comment: I have successfully migrated from GCM to FCM all my install app work perfect with FCM. Issue is only when i upgrade from GCM to FCM.

on old version I was subscribed to topic1 in GCM. Now in new version I am subscribed to new topic2. My old GCM client is runnon on server which pushes notification on older device. As my app is upgraded to FCM, I still receive GCM messages